# Implement ECMA-376 sheetProtection hashing algorithm in Ruby

Tags: ruby, excel, password-encryption

Part 1 of the [ECMA-376 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm)
 (see 18.3.1.85 sheetProtection) details the following three attributes to generate a password hash for sheet protection:

algorithmName

(defaults to SHA-1)

saltValue

Specifies the salt which was prepended to the user-supplied password before it was hashed using the hashing algorithm defined by the preceding attribute values to generate the hashValue attribute, and which shall also be prepended to the user-supplied password before attempting to generate a hash value for comparison.

spinCount

Specifies the number of times the hashing function shall be iteratively run (runs using each iteration's result plus a 4 byte value (0-based, little endian) containing the number of the iteration as the input for the next iteration) when attempting to compare a user- supplied password with the value stored in the hashValue attribute.

I expected something like this to work:

```
def hash_password(v)
  require 'digest/sha1'
  spin_count = 10
  salt_value = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(rand(36**8).to_s(36))
  salty = salt_value + v
  hash_value = nil
  spin_count.times do |count|
    hash_value = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest((hash_value ||= salty ) +  Array(count).pack('V'))
  end
 hash_value
```

end

I'd be truly grateful if anyone can point out what I am doing wrong here.

EDIT: To give a bit more context:

This pseudo code is extracted from the axlsx gem for authoring xlsx spreadsheets. You can see the actual code from around line 155 [here](https://github.com/randym/axlsx/blob/master/lib/axlsx/workbook/worksheet/sheet_protection.rb)

We have been able to implement a much older version of the password hashing Based on the algorithm provided by Daniel Rentz of OpenOffice http://www.openoffice.org/sc/excelfileformat.pdf, Revision 1.42, page 115 (21.05.2012) However this is very different from what is listed in the spec.

If you fork the repo, you can run examples/sheet_protection.rb which creates a workbook with two sheets, one that uses the ECMA spec, the other using OpenOffice's version. If you click 'tools'->'protection'-> 'disable protection' (translating from Japanese here, the actual menu text may be different) and type in the password - it fails with the ECMA version.

## Update: 2012.05.23

Looking a bit deeper, the fourth part of the spec (15.3.1.5, 15.3.1.6) indicates that there is an optional password attribute which conforms to the old style of sheet protection generation for 'transitional conformance classes'

password
(Password)
Specifies the hash of the password required for editing this chart sheet.
The hash is generated using the logic defined in the revisionPassword attribute of the workbookProtection element (Part 1, §18.2.29)

which at least explains why the OpenOffice algorithm still works.

Comment: That function is not going to be very useful without a way to pass in a known salt or get the randomly-generated one back out along with the hash.

Comment: that is excel's job :) - the salt is stored in the serialized xml along with the hash and algorithm name.

Comment: The actual source that I am working against is here: https://github.com/randym/axlsx/blob/master/lib/axlsx/workbook/worksheet/sheet_protection.rb

Answer (score 0):

Does the algorithm assume you're starting at zero or one?

```
irb(main):006:0> 3.times do |t| p t; end
0
1
2
=> 3
```

Maybe try

```
1.upto(10) do |count|
```

instead?

Also, are you sure your numbers are little-endian ordered?  You may want a different pack directive to ensure little-endian-ness.

https://img.skitch.com/20120522-gcsbh4eap247eh2jrubm4qm9tm.jpg

Comment: re: base 0 vs base 1 indices - Ive tried both, with the same results.

Comment: re: little-endian - possibly not. A little research shows that Array(1).pack('V') => "\001\000\000\000" is what I am looking for assuming my understanding of little-endian is correct. Sadly - no-joy

Comment: I've edited the post to use little-endian packing - as that is definitely a step in the right direction! THANKS Jonathan!

Answer (score 0):

I found this while trying to re-implement Excel 2013's password hashing algorithm, so I'm putting this here to help myself in the future.

Excel does the following:

- Concatenates bytes of `saltValue` + password (as UTF-16 bytes).
- Calculates hash based on `algorithmName` (now SHA512 by default) of salt + password.
- Appends the loop count (starting at 0) as four little-endian bytes to the result of the hash.
- Calculates hash of the last result + loop count.
- Repeats calculation `spinCount` times.

The final hash result is what it stores in `hashValue`.

So something like the following should work.

```
def hash_password(v)
  require 'digest/sha1'
  spin_count = 10
  salt_value = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(rand(36**8).to_s(36))
  salty = salt_value + v
  hash_value = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(salty)
  spin_count.times do |count|
    hash_value = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(hash_value + Array(count).pack('V'))
  end
hash_value
```